# Google Chrome Net-internals (NetLog) API

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

Per https://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/providing-network-details

I'm looking for a JavaScript API that triggers a similar functionality of chrome://net-export/ in Google Chrome; for example, I need an API that triggers "Start Logging to Disk" without need to use the UI.

Can someone point me where can I find the API (if exists)?

Thanks a million,

Mughrabi

Comment: This is a part of the browser UI and it doesn't expose any API to extensions.

Comment: The UI is not easy to use, and It requires some background to know what is going on before using it.

Comment: chrome://net-export/net_export.js - I find the API, but it looks like this is not accessible for extensions. I feel Google want to keep it invisible for the extensions.